# Checks user input that distinguishes between pattern forms

Tags: bash

Here's a Bash script that check if user input matches the patterns in the array `pary`, and perform different actions based on whether a match is found or not.

I want to modify this script in a way that if a match occurs with the digit form `"-p+([[:digit:]])"`, I do something, otherwise I do something else.

Currently this script only tests if a match was found rather, but is not capable of distinguishing the matching form.

```
#!/bin/bash

# define the pattern array
pary=( "-p+([[:digit:]])" "-g" )

# get user input
read -p "Enter input: " user_input

# loop through the pattern array and check for a match
match_found=false
for pattern in "${pary[@]}"
do
  if [[ $user_input =~ $pattern ]]
  then
    match_found=true
    break
  fi
done

# perform action based on whether a match was found or not
if $match_found
then
  echo "User input matches a pattern in the array."
  # do something here
else
  echo "User input does not match any pattern in the array."
  # do something else here
fi
```

Comment: What kind of *"user input"* are you waiting for? Please **edit your question** to show some samples!

Comment: Examples of user input would be `-p`, `-p13`,  `-g`, `-h`, `-s245ao`.

Comment: As [@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083725/checks-user-input-that-distinguishes-between-pattern-forms#comment134181171_76083725) "Please **edit your question** ..." and don't ONLY add input, also show the expected output given that input as we can't test one without the other. All relevant information (code, input, and output of the [mcve]) should be in your question, not in comments where it generally can't be formatted and could be missed.

Comment: Make sure when providing examples to include cases that look similar to matching strings but should not match, e.g. idk if `foo-p12` or `-p12foo` or  `-ppppp3` should match `-p+([[:digit:]])` or not (did you mean that to be `-p([[:digit:]]+)` instead?). It's usually trivial to match text that should match but much harder to not match similar text that should not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Writing the correct pattern

If you're going to use `=~`, you can debug your regular expressions by using `$BASH_REMATCH` to see which parts of the input string actually matched.

```bash
input="-pp123x"
pattern="-p+([[:digit:]])"
[[ $input =~ $pattern ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} || echo no match
```

will output "`-pp1`". Your regular expression will match multiple `p` characters, not multiple digits as you intended.

Moving the `+` at the end of the expression will fix that:

```bash
input="-p123x"
pattern="-p([[:digit:]])+"
[[ $input =~ $pattern ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} || echo no match
```

will now output `-p123`. However, it doesn't react to the extra character at the end (and you could also have extras at the beginning, e.g. `input="abc-p123xyz"` would still match).

If you want to match only on `-p<number>` with no additional characters, you need to add `^` and `$` to your matching pattern:

```bash
input="-p123"
pattern="^-p([[:digit:]])+\$"
[[ $input =~ $pattern ]] && echo number: ${input#-p} || echo no match
```

will output `number: 123`

### 2. Parsing multiple choice strings

Placing all your patterns in an array is a viable choice, especially when the array is created programatically or used more than once in a larger script.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input="$1"
arr=( "^-p([[:digit:]])+\$" "-g" )
for pattern in "${arr[@]}"; do
    [[ $input =~ $pattern ]] && echo "array: matched $input"
done
```

An easier (standard?) way to parse arguments in bash is by using `case`. The patterns are [different](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) and you need to enable `extglob`, but you don't have to deal with arrays. Note that you can also use variables here if you want:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

input="$1"
pattern='-p+([[:digit:]])'
case $input in
    $pattern) echo "matched -p with number ${input#-p}";;
    -x+([[:digit:]])) echo "matched -x with number ${input#-p}";;
    -g) echo "matched -g";;
    *) echo "input not recognized: $input";;
esac
```

Comment: Yes, I have multiple patterns stored in an array programmatically.  Because I want to use it more than once in a script library.

Comment: I like the case approach.  But I cannot hardwire the `-p` and `-g` because the pattern is dynamic.  What can I do? Would it be possible to check the input with the array patterns using a case clause?

Comment: @Veak Absolutely, you can use variables in a case statement. I've updated the answer to include an example. There is nothing wrong with using arrays either if that's what works better with your design.

Comment: That was useful information. I need to put another question on my implementation based on the discussion here.

Comment: Want to fix this condition `[[ "$gpn" =~ -[[:alpha:]]([[:digit:]])+ ]] && _vl="${arg1:2}"` because I only want to check if the pattern has the string defining the digit character class `[[:digit:]]`.